# How to add google map and map pins using Xamarin cross platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to the Xamarin. I need to create a small application to make use phone resources and google map.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/ this link should help you build that small app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For resources access like, call, sms, flash on/off you can make use these

```
    phoneDialer.MakePhoneCall(phoneNo);
    smsMessenger.SendSms(phoneNo, smsMessage);
    CrossLamp.Current.TurnOn();
    CrossLamp.Current.TurnOff();
```

I think this will help you get some idea. You can also create a utility class where you can create a function and make use these for all platform and you can call the corresponding functions whenever it is necessary.